# Java: How to check where an object will before it gets there

Tags: java, object

The part of the code I'm up to has a dialog box asking for a user to input a number of units and for an object to ascend the input number. 
However, if the the number of units would cause the objects' y- position = 0 then an alert would pop up and the object wont move.  I have something that works but only after the object has made it's journey.

This is what I have so far:

```
   /*
    * Prompts the user to enter the number of units they want the  
    * rocket to move upwards.
    * 
    * If the number the units provided would cause the tip of the  
    * capsule to go past the top of the Graphical Display, the user 
    * is informed via a dialogue box that the rocket will not launch.  
    * 
    * Otherwise the rocket launches as required. 
    */
   public void launch()
   {
      String inputNumString;
      int inputNum;
      inputNumString = OUDialog.request("Please Enter Number of Units You Wish the Rocket to Ascend");
      inputNum = Integer.parseInt(inputNumString);
      this.ignition();
      this.animateRocket(inputNum);
      this.getCapsule().getYPos();
      if (getCapsule().getYPos() <= 0) 
      {
         OUDialog.alert("Rocket Will Not Launch");



      }

   }
```

Comment: hint: don't ask / think about the very high level problem, you need to think in terms of variables, coordinates and such.

Answer (score 0):

`if(getCapsule().getYPos() - inputNum <=0)`

that should do it

Comment: Sorry no, that hasn't done it. There's still not warning

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the methods do, but you should change your logic to something like this.

```
 public void launch()
   {
      String inputNumString;
      int inputNum;
      inputNumString = OUDialog.request("Please Enter Number of Units You Wish the Rocket to Ascend");
      inputNum = Integer.parseInt(inputNumString);
      this.ignition();
      // calculate new position here
      calculateNewPosition();
      if (getCapsule().getYPos() <= 0) {
         OUDialog.alert("Rocket Will Not Launch");
      } else {
         this.animateRocket(inputNum);
      }

   }
```